# Protected routes using JWT tokens in NextJS + Django

Tags: django, axios, next.js, jwt

I'm starting this new NextJS application where I'm using Django as an API.

I'm using JWT tokens for authentication/authorization and I wanted to create protected routes. After following a bunch of tutorials, videos and other things online, here's what I came up with:

I created an axios instance (**api.js**) (where I was trying to intercept requests to set the Authorization header):

```js
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "js-cookie";


const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});

api.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  const token = Cookies.get("accessToken");
  if (token) {
    api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token.access}`;
  }
  return request;
});

export default api;
```

And an **AuthService.js** (where I set a cookie when l log in):

```js
    import Cookies from "js-cookie";
    import api from "./api";
    
    export const AuthService = {
      login: async (email, password) => {
        const { data: token } = await api.post("token/", { email, password });
        console.log(token);
        if (token) {
          console.log("Got token");
          Cookies.set("accessToken", token.access, { expires: 60 });
          api.defaults.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token.access}`;
          const { data: user } = await api.get("users/current/");
          console.log("Got user", user);
    
          return user;
        }
      },
    
      logout: async () => {
        Cookies.remove("accessToken");
        delete api.defaults.headers.Authorization;
      },
    
      getUser: async () => {
        try {
          const { data: user } = await api.get("users/current/");
          return user;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error", error);
        }
      },
    };
```

Then, in my **AuthContext** I have a higher-order function (requireAuthentication) that accepts another function (in my case getServerSideProps) and redirect to the login page if the access token is not set or is invalid:

```js
const AuthContext = createContext({});

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const login = async (email, password) => {
    ...
  };

  const logout = () => {
    ...
  };

  const getUser = async () => {
    ...
  };

  const contextValues = {
    ...
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={contextValues}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default AuthContext;

export function requireAuthentication(gssp) {
  return async (context) => {
    const { req } = context;

    if (req.cookies) {
      const accessToken = req.cookies["accessToken"];

      try {
        const user = await AuthService.getUser();
        console.log("user", user);

        if (!accessToken || !user || !user.email) {
          return {
            redirect: {
              permanent: false,
              destination: "/login",
            },
          };
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return {
          redirect: {
            permanent: false,
            destination: "/login",
          },
        }; 
      }
    }

    return gssp(context);
  };
}
```

I can then use this higher-order function on the components that I need to be "protected" as so:

```js
import { requireAuthentication } from "../../contexts/AuthContext";

export default function Dashboard({ props }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps = requireAuthentication((context) => {
  // normal `getServerSideProps` code here
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  };
});
```

I think I know why this does not work - when I intercept requests the cookie is undefined because I'm using getServerSideProps and cookies are on the client side.

From what I've read, I could use httponly cookies for this strategy to work, but I don't know how.

Is the approach I'm using common/good? Can someone please help me with the httponly cookie if that will fix my problem?

Please, let me know if have suggestions and advices on how to have "protected routes" using JWT tokens.

Thank you.

Comment: The cookies will be available inside `getServerSideProps` from `context.req.cookies`. The issue might be in the axios' interceptor when you try to access the cookie with `const token = Cookies.get("accessToken");` on the server-side. Maybe you need to access it in a different way in that scenario.